# Rearrange object using AngularJS forEach

Tags: angularjs

I want to rearrange an object in AngularJS which looks like this:

```
var persons = [
  {socialnum : "123", pname: "Malcom Reynolds"},
  {socialnum : "456", pname: "Kaylee Frye"},
  {socialnum : "789", pname: "Jayne Cobb"}
];
```

Result should be like this:

```
var persons = [
  {socialnum : "123", pname: "123 - Malcom Reynolds"},
  {socialnum : "456", pname: "456 - Kaylee Frye"},
  {socialnum : "789", pname: "789 - Jayne Cobb"}
];
```

What i tried is this:

```
angular.forEach(persons , function (key, value) {    
this.push(values.socialnum + ' - ' + values.pname);    
}, persons );
```

I did not received the output i wanted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try below code....
since you are already have the array and trying to edit its value, no need to add push function. Just need to update value as given below

```js
var persons = [
  {socialnum : "123", pname: "Malcom Reynolds"},
  {socialnum : "456", pname: "Kaylee Frye"},
  {socialnum : "789", pname: "Jayne Cobb"}
];


angular.forEach(persons , function (key, value) {  
key['pname'] = key['socialnum']+' - '+ key['pname']   
}, persons );
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.7.5/angular.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use [Map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) to do this.

```
let newArray = persons.map(value => {
  return {socialnum: value.socialnum, pname: value.socialnum + ' - ' + value.pname};
});
```